# What test should I use?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln(n+1)}$$

What test should I use to prove whether the series converges or diverges? I tried using the integral test however I'm not so sure how to integrate the integral.

Comment: Hint:  Prove $\ln(n)<n$.

Comment: the comparison test?

Comment: @ salierii Yes, because the harmonic series diverges.

Comment: Of course, it's even enough to show that $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac {\ln(n)}n=0$, but it's not hard to demonstrate the term by term inequality.

Comment: Thank you! Could I get any clarification? I am confused where did ln(n) < n come from? I am assuming that An <= Bn. Shouldn't it be something like 1/ ln(n+1) <= 1/ln(n) ?

Comment: The index doesn't matter.  Rewrite the sum as $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac 1{\ln n}$ if you want.  And it's an important fact that $ln(x)$ grows more slowly than any polynomial.

Comment: @lulu You already provided an answer in your comments... maybe you could make it official!

Comment: Another question. Should I use the comparison test or the limit comparison test?

Comment: @salierii use which ever one works for what you want to say in your proof.

Comment: Another follow-up question. I tried doing this:
* 1/ln(n+1) < 1/ln(n)
It follows that 1/ln(n) > 1/n. And by the comparison test, if an >= bn, then it is divergent
I am not so sure with my proof.

Comment: It is true that $\frac{1}{\ln(n+1)} < \frac{1}{\ln n}.\ $ But I don't see *why it follows from this* that $\frac{1}{\ln n} > \frac{1}{n}.$